# Getting starting with github - out of VIM window

Tags: vim, batch-file, github

I am starting with github. After the commands $ git commit -m (without a 'message'), I reach a [image: VIM] window. I added some text on top to explain the commit... but I am stuck there, how to EsCape?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To commit, save and quit the way you normally do in vim. `:x`, `:wq`, `:w` followed by `:q`, `ZZ`, whatever.

To abort you can use `:cq`.

If you'd rather use something other than vim (it isn't clear if your problem is that you don't know vim or are just confused that git dropped you in vim) you can change `$EDITOR` to whatever editor you'd prefer. See `git help commit` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer: Hit escape to exit normal mode in Vim, then `:wq`, `:x` or `ZZ` to write and quit (`:q!` to exit Vim, which will cancel your commit).

You can also change your editor settings in Git so you don't have to use Vim.

For instance, you could set your editor to emacs with:

```
git config --global core.editor emacs
```

Git is using Vim because that's your system's default editor. An alternative is to change your system editor. To change to pico (a simple editor with little to offer in features):

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/pico
```

*edit*: Oops, I just noticed you're using Windows. The previous bash command will not apply to you, but I'll leave it here as a general tip.